RuntimeError: unable to mmap bytes from file; Cannot allocate memory when loading checkpoint shards (Llama 3.2)
I am trying to load a Llama 3.2 model on my Amazon Linux 2 server, using huggingface: https://huggingface.co/unsloth/Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct
I am using the following code from their docs:
import requests
import torch
from PIL import Image
from transformers import MllamaForConditionalGeneration, AutoProcessor

model_id = "meta-llama/Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct"
model = MllamaForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_id, device_map="auto", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

messages = [
    [
        {
            "role": "user", 
            "content": [
                {"type": "image"},
                {"type": "text", "text": "What does the image show?"}
            ]
        }
    ],
]
text = processor.apply_chat_template(messages, add_generation_prompt=True)

url = "https://llava-vl.github.io/static/images/view.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

inputs = processor(text=text, images=image, return_tensors="pt").to(model.device)
output = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=25)
print(processor.decode(output[0]))

It actually says it has loaded 5/5 models:
config.json: 100%|5.16k/5.16k [00:00<00:00, 34.6MB/s]

model.safetensors.index.json: 100%|[00:00<00:00, 57.0MB/s]
model-00001-of-00005.safetensors: 100%|[00:35<00:00, 142MB/s]
model-00002-of-00005.safetensors: 100%|[00:36<00:00, 135MB/s]
model-00003-of-00005.safetensors: 100%|[00:36<00:00, 135MB/s]
model-00004-of-00005.safetensors: 100%|[00:37<00:00, 135MB/s]
model-00005-of-00005.safetensors: 100%|[00:10<00:00, 135MB/s]
Downloading shards: 100%| [02:36<00:00, 31.38s/it]

However when I get to this line:
The model weights are not tied. Please use the 'tie_weights' method before using the 'infer_auto_device' function.
Loading checkpoint shards:   0%|

I get the following error:
RuntimeError: unable to mmap 4992622346 bytes from file </home/ec2-user/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--unsloth--Llama-3.2-11B-Vision-Instruct/snapshots/245b40ec384690450f4f0c967d31356ba9065a35/model-00001-of-00005.safetensors>: Cannot allocate memory (12)

Is this due to a lack of RAM?

Hi, How much RAM do you have? My kernel goes out of memory while downloading the model. I have tried Colab and Kaggle notebooks. Both give the same error.
